How to handle ABAC efficiently for unbound number of entities?
I am implementing ABAC for different objects/users.
All works good when I need to GET single object. Policy rules are enforced and all good.
Issue are collections.
When I have collections, especially unbound ones and the ones that includw pagination - how to enforce policies in that case?
My gut feeling tells me that policies should return more than just allow|deny in that case. Maybe some predicate that is being added to filter db for records?
Not sure how to implement it and still having policy rules not leaked to DAL?
